# Underscore in Lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda

I am working through the following explanation of the implementation of the experimental Boost::DI dependency injection framework:

http://boost-experimental.github.io/di/cppnow-2016/#/7/22

In there the following code is presented:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... Ns>
constexpr auto getCnstrSize (std::index_sequence<Ns...>) noexcept {
    auto value = 0;
    int _[]{(is_constructible<T, std::make_index_sequence<Ns>>{}? value = Ns 
    : value)...};
return value;
}
```

I am specifically interested in the Lambda. I understand it functionality, it goes through the `index_sequence`, and sets value if the type `T` has a constructor with that number of arguments.

What has me stumped is the underscore. I have fiddled around, and I cannot take it away. I also cannot insert an equality like `_=[]`, so it is not a variable name. My question is, what does it do?

Comment: It's not a lambda, `int _[]` defines an *array* variable named `_`. Instead of `_=[]...` you try `_[] = ...` then it should work better.

Comment: Using this strange thing is to expand the pack. In C++17, comma's fold expression will be more natural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underscore is just a variable name within that lexical block. It is constructed using what looks to be an `initializer_list` populated by a [pack expansion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion). It's not a lambda, it just looks confusing because of the initializer list using `{}`.